# My database connection doesn't work in laravel. I can connect through CLI but not in the webapp

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

in CLI mysql works fine and i can connect to Database, but when i try a DB::connection()->getPDO() it goes to catch and says the following:

> "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client"

in CLI when i type SHOW TABLES; it does dump

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| clients        |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

I am using Mysql locally using brew services start mysql.
I am a beginner when it comes to laravel and php development, this is school assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake.
In tableplus I had to run the query:

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

I found this on another stackoverflow question.